# Replace within the html of some JQuery object

Tags: jquery, replace

If I have some JQuery object `$("#someDiv")`, for which its html(),

```
$("#someDiv").html();
```

equals something like:

```
<div id="bla_i">
  <input ... id="ble_i" />
</div>
```

(That is: a lot of nested elements, some of them having id's and names containing " _i ")

**How can I make all those "_i" to be "_5" ?**
How can I replace all the "_i" in some JQuery Object?

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = $('#someDiv').html();  // get the html string

$(html)  // make jQuery object
       .find('[id*="_i"]')  // find elements with id contains "_i"
       .attr('id',function(i, oldId) {
          return oldId.replace('_i', '_5');  // replace all "_i" with "_5"
       });
```